# Webpack JS minify

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs, minify

I'm impressed by [jscompress.com](https://jscompress.com/) (ECMAScript 2021 (via babel-minify) and wanted to do the same compression on my Webpack JS file. Tried `babel-minify-webpack-plugin` and it outputs `ERROR in unknown: Unexpected token (115:14)`.

So without the plugin below is the config I have on `webpack.config.js`. Without the plugin, compression works. but adding some more codes to the file and the compression is not very good as the `jscompress.com`.

```
// webpack.config.js
const path = require('path')

module.exports = {
    optimization: {
        minimize: true,
    },
    mode: 'production',
    entry: './src/myfile.js',
    output: {
        filename: 'web.js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
    },
    plugins: [],
    module: {}
}
```

```
// This code added automatically before my code when I don't use the plugin.

!function(e){var r={};function t(o){if(r[o])return r[o].exports;var c=r[o]={i:o,l:!1,exports:{}};return e[o].call(c.exports,c,c.exports,t),c.l=!0,c.exports}t.m=e,t.c=r,t.d=function(e,r,o){t.o(e,r)||Object.defineProperty(e,r,{enumerable:!0,get:o})},t.r=function(e){"undefined"!=typeof Symbol&&Symbol.toStringTag&&Object.defineProperty(e,Symbol.toStringTag,{value:"Module"}),Object.defineProperty(e,"__esModule",{value:!0})},t.t=function(e,r){if(1&r&&(e=t(e)),8&r)return e;if(4&r&&"object"==typeof e&&e&&e.__esModule)return e;var o=Object.create(null);if(t.r(o),Object.defineProperty(o,"default",{enumerable:!0,value:e}),2&r&&"string"!=typeof e)for(var c in e)t.d(o,c,function(r){return e[r]}.bind(null,c));return o},t.n=function(e){var r=e&&e.__esModule?function(){return e.default}:function(){return e};return t.d(r,"a",r),r},t.o=function(e,r){return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(e,r)},t.p="",t(t.s=0)}([function(e,r,t){(function(t){var o,c,n;

// My code is from here onwards
```

Can anyone help me to compress the JS file correctly?

Comment: Can you share what you have done like: the plugin configuration/ the file code and the package json?